# java socket fileoutputstream can't close file

Tags: java, sockets, netbeans, fileoutputstream

i've write a code for transferring file over sockets,
the file is transfers properly but it isn't closed even after calling `.close()` method.

however the file closes after closing the "sockets", but i want to keep the connection open.

here the **server** sends the file to **client**

SERVER CODE

```
public  void sendFile(String sfileName) throws IOException{
    try{
        in = new FileInputStream(sfileName);
        out = socket.getOutputStream();
        transferData(in,out);
    }
    finally {
        in.close();
        in = null;
        System.gc();
    }
}
private void transferData(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException  {
    byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
    int len = 0;
    while(in.available()==0);
    while ((len = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
    out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    out.flush();
}
```

CLIENT CODE :

```
public  void recieveFile(String rfileName) throws IOException{
    try{
        in = socket.getInputStream();
        System.out.println("Reciever file : " + rfileName);
        out = new FileOutputStream(rfileName);
        transferData(in,out);
    }
    finally{
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        out = null;
        System.gc();
    }
}
private void transferData(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException  {
    byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
    int len = 0;
    while(in.available()==0);
    while ((len = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
    out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    out.flush();
}
```

what is wrong with the code ?

Comment: How do you know that the file is not closed? Do the changes not get written to disk?

Comment: the file can't deleted, renamed etc... but the file size is okay. however after closing the connection or terminating program, it works. ....

Comment: I suspect that your read() is going to block, waiting for more information to arrive, hence why it doesn't terminate and your file isn't closed. Maybe read a preset number of bytes rather than waiting for -1?

Comment: but even the file should be closed, bcoz i've put the close() method in finally block ...]

Comment: Not if it hasn't reached the finally block - I think it might be stck in the `transferData()` method, waiting on the `read(buf)` - try sticking a breakpoint in the finally and see if it reaches it normally.

Comment: yes the code control reaches at finally block ...

Comment: That loop that spins while available() is zero is literally a waste of time. Remove it. The following read will block, rather than smoking the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [Socket.shutdownOutput()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#shutdownOutput%28%29)

Comment: yes the file closes after Socket.shutdownOutput() but the problem is i want to keep "Open" the connection for further file transfers ...